# Lower the level of a label in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am finding when I use label vector lines using the newer labeling tool that the labels always appear on top of the lines of that layer. And they appear on top of all other layers in my project. Is there a way to have these labels lower down (i.e. not on top of other layers).

Thanks,
David

Comment: Is there anything new ? I'm intersted in it.

Answer (score 2):

No that's currently not possible. Labels are always on top.

An ugly solution is to save the layers you want in the back to an image ("Save as image") and load that image back into QGIS - then overlay the things you want to be on top.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I appreciate as well your workaround. Like you said a little ugly so I will only use it if I really need to. Is there a way I can add this as a request for future builds of QGIS?

Comment: @David, the existing [feature request #5628 "optional "Layer Order" entries for Labels and Diagrams"](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5628) looks to be the same (or very similar) to what you are requesting. Since it is marked as unplanned, I suppose if it is really important to you, you could always consider funding it as a project.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in a straight-forward way. 
You can, though, achieve a similiar result without tampering with the layer/label stacking order.

My example refers to a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224799/place-names-ignoring-layer-order) marked as a duplicate.
The person asking said question had three layers: a base layer, a point layer which served for labelling, and a semi-transparent mask layer; in this order from bottom to top. They wanted the labels to be affected by the semi-transparent mask layer.

[image: original situation]

My approach uses the “join by location” tool from the Processing tool box to assign an extra attribute to the label layer, which later allows us to style the labels in a rule-based manner (the ones “behind” the mask being transparent themselves)

EDIT: I assume that your polygon layer has a column describing whether the mask is applied for the current feature or not. This column is the attribute you want to transfer in the `join by location` step. In my case the column is called `masked` and contains the values 0 and 1, respectively. You can also use any existing attribute of the polygons, just be sure to refer to the right attribute when you create the rules for styling the output layer (last step)

[image: join by location]

[image: rule-based label styles]

The results look like that:
[image: final]